# in xCode, launching iPad Pro still launches in 768x1004px mode

Tags: ios, xcode, launchimage

I have provided the iPad Pro App iOS 9-10 83.5pt icon for the App Image but don't see a slot for the Launch Image.

I would like to use the launch images over the Storyboard and I read that you were able to do it this way since xCode8.  Is there another button or something I need to tick to enable iPad Pro?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was using an older LaunchImage icon set.. creating a new one provided with the correct image slots.